# action script 3.0 .I had tried a program that should move the dragger as well as the content movieclip,

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

In this code i need a progressbar to progress through while the imported .swf file is playing, meanwhile i should able to drag the dragger in the progress bar (i.e the rate of movement of dragger should sync with rate of .swf file playing). I got Argument error: #2109 Frame label 459.99 not found in scene1.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
playBtn.visible = true;

pauseBtn.visible = false;
btn_00.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fileLoaded);
btn_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fileLoaded);
btn_02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fileLoaded);
function fileLoaded(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var fileName:String = evt.currentTarget.name;
    var fileNumber:String = fileName.split("_")[1];
    var urlPath:String = "assets/file_" + fileNumber + ".swf";
    loader.load(new URLRequest(urlPath));
    addChild(loader);
}
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
function swfLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, trackPlayback);
}
function trackPlayback(event:Event):void
{
    var perPlayed:Number = MovieClip(loader.content).currentFrame / MovieClip(loader.content).totalFrames;
    progressbar.drag.x = (progressbar.bar.width - progressbar.drag.width) * perPlayed;
}
progressbar.drag.buttonMode = true;
var dragClicked:Boolean = false;
var xpos:Number = progressbar.bar.x * progressbar.drag.width;
progressbar.drag.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragMouseDown);
function dragMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(" inside mouse down ");
    dragClicked = true;
    progressbar.drag.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(xpos,0,progressbar.width-progressbar.drag.width,0));
}

progressbar.drag.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dragMouseUp);
function dragMouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    dragClicked = false;
    progressbar.drag.stopDrag();
    var cnt:Number = (progressbar.drag.x/(progressbar.width-progressbar.drag.width))*MovieClip(loader.content).totalFrames;
    MovieClip(loader.content).gotoAndPlay(cnt);
  }
```

Pls solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To access a specific frame, you need to provide an integer value where at the moment you are using a floating-point value.

A simple fix would be to cast the `Number` to an `int`:

```
MovieClip(loader.content).gotoAndPlay(int(cnt));
```